# Best way to go about file properties

Tags: c#

Whats the best way to read/write file properties (like author, description, etc) in C#? 
I can use dsofile.dll to accomplish this but I wonder if this is the right way to go. (being unmanaged code?)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft explicitly [recommends](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=224351) dsofile.dll for use with .NET. Not sure why you think this would be inappropriate - it ultimately uses the very code that other structured file readers also use. Reimplementing this in managed code would be error-prone, and likely does more harm than good.